# Will this Linksys Cisco switch work for the CCNA exam?

Tags: untagged

[image]
[image: enter link description here]

If I can use this to train for the CCNA exam, do I just need a DB-9 to RJ-45 rollover cable and just plug the rollover cable into the ethernet port of my computer?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is a Linksys switch, which does not run IOS, and would not be helpful in studying for any Cisco Exam... I'm especially dubious on account of the console port being a DB9 and not Cisco's blue RJ45 standard.

Comment: If you're looking for training only, try using [Packet Life's Free Cisco Training Lab](http://packetlife.net/lab/). It's got all the equipment you need to study for almost all of the Cisco Exams.

Comment: All of the below answers are correct, but it WOULD be good practice to make this switch interact with a real Cisco switch or router so you can get a firm grasp on vendor inter-operability.

Comment: Spiff - only if it's got enterprise features that are worth incorporating into a serious network. And even then, it doesn't really aid jyim in his goal of passing the CCNA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No and no.  Linksys switches do not run IOS that is tested against.  The console port of Cisco hardware is serial but has a 8P8C connector (RJ45) so  the rollover cable goes the other way (DB9 on your computer -> 8P8C on the Cisco device).   To connect to that Linksys switch you would need a null modem DB9F<->DB9F cable.  But again the interface you get on the console of that switch will not be IOS and not be the same as a Catalyst.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't.. I would look into a software solution to emulator/simulate IOS devices. Check out the following

http://www.gns3.net/

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  It won't work.  That's not a Cisco switch.  It's a Linksys switch with Cisco written on.

It's like having Ferarri written on a Ford Fiesta.  That doesn't mean it'll go faster.. it just means that it's been sloppily rebadged.

With regard to the console port, you'll need either a true serial port, or a USB-Serial converter. [image: One using the PL2303 chipset, like this.]

Linksys switches (even those badged as Cisco) don't run IOS that you'll be studying for CCNA and further Cisco qualifications.

Either use GNS3 (which is a great router emulator), or Cisco's Packet Tracer (which I personally hate).  Or do what I did, and buy 3 Cisco 26xx routers and 2 Cisco catalyst 2950 switches, and a Rollover cable, and do it the proper way.
[image: Cisco Rollover Cable]

Answer (score 0):

this switch has a lot of the features you need to study for the CCNA but this switch is not much use as it does not use IOS as its operating system. It does have a console port but this is a text based menu only. If you want CCNA switches you should look at the catalyst series, a 2950 is a good start if you are looking at ebay or a 2960-S if you are buying new.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say "No." It doesn't run IOS. It supports very few of the actual technologies that are covered in the exam. And your understanding of the console port is off - that's serial, not ethernet.

http://www.certificationkits.com/linksys-ccna-lab/